# Add field using ALTER TABLE in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to add a field to a table in access through vba by using an `ALTER TABLE` statement and change the data type as well.  I almost have the whole statement written but I am unsure how to put in the data type.  I want it to be a yes/no field.

```
AddTable="ALTER TABLE [ShouldImportMetricsIDs] " & _
"ADD [Import Status]......"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
ALTER TABLE ShouldImportMetricsIDs
ADD COLUMN [Import Status] YESNO;
```

You can find more syntax information from Microsoft's page: [ALTER TABLE Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx)

Allen Browne has a page with the DDL names for Access datatypes: [Field type reference](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html)

Comment: How would I set the default value for this field then?

Comment: Access DDL supports a `DEFAULT` keyword when the statement is executed from ADO.  That works for `CREATE TABLE`, but unfortunately I can't get it to work with `ALTER TABLE`.  As a fallback, you could modify the `DAO.TableDef` like this ... `CurrentDb.TableDefs("ShouldImportMetricsIDs").Fields("Import Status").DefaultValue = True`

Comment: I try that but it said item not found in this collection. Yet when I check my table, the field does exist. And all the spelling is the same...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why it failed.  That was a copy and paste from my Access session, and it worked here.  You may need to create a new question for setting the default.